# Why can't I open ANY web page with the EPM box unchecked in IE10 on Windows 7 x64?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, pdf

I upgraded from IE9 to IE10 on my Win 7 64 bit computer through the automatic updates through Win 7.

As soon as the upgrade completed I tried to open a webpage and got the error message: "This Page Can't Be Displayed". I researched and found out the "Enable Enhanced Protected Mode" needed to be checked in the security section of IE10 options. I checked the box and now all my web pages work.

My question is why can't I open ANY web page with the EPM box unchecked? I'm trying to open certain PDF files in a few of my financial web sites that give me error messages related to AcroPDF.dll when trying to open their PFD files.

Am I correct in that unchecking the "Enable Enhanced Protected Mode" box puts IE10 in 32 bit mode? And why doesn't >**ANY**< web page I select open when the Enabled Enhanced Protected Mode box is unchecked? I get "This Page Can't Be Displayed"

Comment: Related: [Unable to open IE 10 in 32-bit mode](http://superuser.com/questions/561036/unable-to-open-ie-10-in-32-bit-mode)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out my problem was a third party add-on called Simple Adblock. After I uninstalled and removed it from my system EI10 now works perfectly in either 32x or 64x mode.

What threw me off was that I had disabled this add on in addition to unticking the "Enbable third-party browser extensions" under IE10's advanced options section. That didn't work until the Simple Adblock extension was completely deleted from my system.