# Does one need both a 32bit and 64bit version of Java?

Tags: java, 32-vs-64-bit

I notice I keep getting Java updates, even right after I install one. Right now I have both 32bit and 64bit, can I get rid of one? I don't know how I got two.
[image: my add/remove programs]

Right now my antivirus is complaining that one of the Javas is out of date.

Comment: You only need 64-bit Java if you want to run 64-bit Java Applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not (actually one would hope you don't need Java support in the browser at all, but that's unrealistic for many). Even in 64 bit Windows the default IE client is the 32 bit version. Unless you need Java support in the 64 bit version of IE don't install it. It also seems that the 64 bit version doesn't auto-update in any fashion (they may have changed that).

Comment: 64 bit gives much better performance in most apps and it shouldn't matter if the launching program is 32 bit, it can still run the 64 bit java.

Comment: @psusi reference? That seems odd that most would, considering the small functionality of most apps, and the fact that the JIT compiler would have to compile for a wider address range to do the same amount of small tasks... Even reading this it appears some tricks are required at least some of the time to get the x64 to perform on par with x86... http://lowtek.ca/roo/2008/java-performance-in-64bit-land/

Comment: @AthomSfere, minecraft for one, recommends using a 64 bit java runtime if you want to enable the highest graphics modes as the performance is too slow under 32 bit.  That article appears to be from 2008, so is rather out of date being from the earliest days of 64 bit.

Comment: @psusi Minecraft is an exception more than the rule though. Very few Java applications are games compared to small single application calculators,  config utilities for various network gear and the like.

Comment: @AthomSfere, and the article you linked even says "until recently, moving from a 32bit java to a 64bit java mean taking a performance hit."  So even then it had already been fixed.

Comment: @psusi: "it shouldn't matter if the launching program is 32 bit, it can still run the 64 bit java" - You mean 32-bit IE can load the 64-bit Java plugin? Are you sure?

Comment: @Karan, AFAIK, java isn't a plugin; it's a program.  You run the java program, and it interprets the java code.  As such, a 32 bit program can run a 64 bit program.

Comment: @psusi: The Java code itself is not 32 or 64-bit AFAIK. Anyway, at this point I'm not sure whether the OP really is a coder who wants Java, or perhaps just wants JRE (which *is* primarily a browser plugin BTW).

Comment: @Karan: My answer was based on that assumption - just wants a jre browser plugin, think a coder wouldn't be asking this question like this.

Comment: @darkphader: I agree, but hopefully the OP can confirm. If indeed he's talking about JRE then the 64-bit plugin is unlikely to work in a 32-bit browser. Oh, and regarding your statement about 32-bit IE being the default, that has changed with IE10 ([for Manager Processes at least and optionally for Content Processes as well](http://superuser.com/a/561453/138343)).

Comment: I suppose there must be a stub plugin somewhere that is just responsible for launching the java interpreter, which runs in its own process, and that the stub itself has to match the arch of the browser, but I would think that sun would be smart enough to include both the 32bit and 64bit stubs with the 64bit JRE.  Then again, maybe I'm giving them too much credit.

Comment: I want to be able to code Java.

Comment: I don't see anything else saying its faster even now, and even Minecraft might not be that its faster as much as it can handle the large data chunks better. Saying it generally faster needs some proof. I am not calling it wrong, but it sounds iffy.

Comment: @AthomSfere, it is widely accepted that 64bit is generally faster due to having many more registers to use to avoid memory I/O.  Of course, in practice, your mileage may vary and you may not notice any difference.  There are many benchmarks out there of all sorts of loads showing this general trend, though some specific workloads are slower, and more than a few make little to no difference.  The x32 ABI is currently being developed to stick to 32 bit pointers while keeping the other benefits of 64bit so all loads will be at least as fast as 32bit, and most faster.

Comment: @psusi that's not correct in most cases. Although 64bit is theoretically faster it is not always and not always automatically. Every pointer is also going to be twice as wide, so unless you have tasks that the wider path of the math outperforms the wider pointers you might not see a difference. From Sun: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#64bit_performance it really depends on workload, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589057/does-java-64bit-perform-better-than-the-32bit-version and I suspect **most** benefit is not accurate.

Comment: @AthomSfere, that's pretty much what I said minus the nit picking over the exact proportion of workloads that see benefit and ignoring the higher register count ( it isn't just about the width ).

Comment: Its not just about any one attribute, but "64 bit is faster in most apps" does not sound right, and I can't see any references to verify it.

Comment: Why do I only get the 32-bit Java when I go to Java.com?
Java.com provides a Java version based on your browser and operating system (OS). If you are running a 64-bit version of Windows 8, you have access to 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Internet Explorer 10 on your system. The desktop version of the Windows 8 OS does not run in a full 64-bit mode (unless you have Enhanced Protected Mode in Internet Explorer 10 turned on), thus 32-bit Java is the default.