# Is it possible to run IE10 32-bit frame in Windows 7,8 64-bit?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

Is it possible to run IE10 32-bit frame in Windows 7,8 64-bit?

I know there is a way to change the bit for IE tabs. But Windows 64-bit always runs IE 64-bit frame even though I run it from under the `Program Files (x86)` folder.

Comment: What you describe is not possible.  If IE is being ran out of the `Program Files x96` folder then you are running the 32-bit browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to open IE 10 in 32-bit mode](http://superuser.com/questions/561036/unable-to-open-ie-10-in-32-bit-mode)

Comment: @Ramhound: Not true. With IE10+ even if you manually execute the 32-bit iexplore.exe it will still launch the 64-bit EXE and the 32-bit version will then terminate. The frame/manager process (which the OP wants to know about) *cannot* be executed in 32-bit mode any longer on 64-bit Windows (see [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/561453/138343) to the question mentioned above), although with Enhanced Protected Mode disabled and some registry tweaking (see [the other answer](http://superuser.com/a/566026/138343)) tabs can be executed as 32-bit processes.