# IE10 does not open .pdf

Tags: windows-7, pdf, internet-explorer-10

I can't open any PDFs in IE10 on Win7 64bit.

I've tested with PDFs from Intranet / Internet / local file system, http and https. I've tested installing/uninstalling Acrobat Reader 11.0.03 and the Nitro PDF Reader. I've also tried enabling/disabling the  **Tools** > **Internet Options** > **Advanced** > **Security** > **Do not save encrypted pages to disk** option.

In Google Chrome PDFs are opened in the Acrobat Reader Plugin, but in IE10 the only thing I always get is a small cross in the top left corner of the browser.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: does this happen also in firefox with the pdf viewer plugin?

Comment: In firefox pdf's are also open correct in the acrobat reader plugin.

Comment: You want IE to open a PDF in IE or open the file with Acrobat?

Comment: When possible i would like to open it in IE with the Acrobat Plugin.

Comment: have you tried clear the "Display PDF in browser" option in Acrobat Reader -> Edit menu -> Preferences -> Internet ?

Comment: Yes, no change. I also tried deactivation activating the acrobat plugin. And deinstalling / installing the Acrobat Reader. Without any change in the behavior. There is still just a small cross displayed in the top left corner.

Comment: @user203298: Post your solution as an answer below instead of a mere comment that others might miss. If modifying TabProcGrowth solved the issue, looks like Adobe Reader's plugin is 32-bit whereas IE10 is 64-bit, so you need that change to make IE10's tab processes be 32-bit too. See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/610402/is-it-possible-to-run-ie10-32-bit-frame-in-windows-7-8-64-bit?lq=1#comment755745_610402) and [here](http://superuser.com/questions/561036/unable-to-open-ie-10-in-32-bit-mode) for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution worked for me.
[Pdf won't open while running IE10 on Win7](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie10-windows_7/pdf-wont-open-while-running-ie10-on-windows-7/865a7ed2-ec94-4b77-a6e1-a9de6fb8f40a)

1. Close IE
2. Open the regestry with regedit Start -> type regedit + enter -> change “HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\TabProcGrowth =1 instead of  0 .
3. Reopen IE and try to open a pdf.

See also:
[32-bit browser applications may not work as expected in Internet Explorer 10](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2716529/en-us)

Answer (score 1):

- Uninstall all PDF readers
- Reset Internet Explorer (click the gear in the top right corner of IE>Internet Options>Advanced tab>Reset button>Reset button. Close IE.
- Download Adobe Reader from: get.adobe.com/reader

Comment: Thank you, but still IE10 just show page with a small cross in the top left corner. The html code of the page is['code'](<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML Transitional//EN"><META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=unicode">

<html>
<head><style>

</style></head>


<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" scroll="no"> <embed width="100%" height="100%" src="file:///C:/Bus_15.pdf" type="application/pdf" fullscreen="yes" /></body></html>)

Comment: You could try uninstalling Acrobat and trying a different reader ( http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/ ). Maybe post a screenshot of what you are getting.

Comment: Ok with this solution i found on 
[Pdf won't open while running IE10 on Win7][1] I could solve the problem.

 1. Close IE
 2. Changed “HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\TabProcGrowth =1 instead of  0
 3. Reopen IE and try to open a pdf, in my case it worked


  [1]: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie10-windows_7/pdf-wont-open-while-running-ie10-on-windows-7/865a7ed2-ec94-4b77-a6e1-a9de6fb8f40a