# How to run 32-bit IE 11 browser on Windows 8.1 64 bit

Tags: 64-bit, windows-8.1, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Is it possible to run Internet Explorer 11 32 bit on Windows 8.1 64 bit? Since only 32 bit ActiveX is available for Check Point Software VPN. Currently when I go into site it wants me to download the Java version.

Even when \Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplorer.exe is clicked the 64 bit version of IE is launched.

(The three answers given to a previous similar question ([Unable to open IE 10 in 32-bit mode](https://superuser.com/questions/561036/unable-to-open-ie-10-in-32-bit-mode)) do not apply. The first answer mentions a registery entry which is absent on my pc Windows 7 64 bit and IE 10 32 bit does not work on my case. Since the registery does not contain the mentioned "TabProcGrowth")

Comment: The default behavior is to launch the 32-bit browser. Are you sure the 64-bit browser is being lauched because executable your using is a 32-bit application.

Comment: Could you try creating the registry value mentioned in the duplicate question? It may well be that without the value in place at all it is defaulting to 0 as mentioned in the duplicate.